# advice on how to drag / drop in ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-parts

Okay so I want a simple SINGLE web page that can take a little man, and drag him to a playing field (just a background shaped liek a soccer field) , then click a "save" button and it saves the coordinates. BUT I need the ability to add more little men to the play field.

How would I do this? I was looking at the JQuery Droppable control / ASP.NEt combo, but I Don't see an example of someone saving all the coordinates to a database.

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you can do it by using asp.net web part control

Answer (score 6):

There are many possible method. I use the library Telerik for asp.

- **Telerik**(paying) -
  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/functionality/draganddropnodes/defaultcs.aspx
- **Ajax dragAndDrop via reorderlist** -
  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/reorderlist/drag-and-drop-via-reorderlist-cs
- **DragAndDrop with asp.net** - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135985.aspx
- **DragAndDrop with HTML 5** - http://www.developer.com/lang/using-html5-drag-and-drop-in-asp.net.html

All these links are models "Drag And Drop" technology for asp